# Web3 contract transactions not showing up in Ganache

Tags: web3js, transactions

I am making a contract instance with web3 and then calling a function of the instance.

I don't know why this isn't automatically mining in the local Ganache.

```
var Logistics = new web3js.eth.Contract(LogisticsData.abi, LogisticsAddress);
console.log(Logistics);
var newBox = Logistics.methods._createBox("0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10", "0xf25186b5081ff5ce73482ad761db0eb0d25abfbf");
console.log(newBox);
```

[image: Console Log]

Comment: How is your function `_createBox` defined? Perhaps it is defined as view or constant?

Comment: It's supposed to create a Box contract, which should definitely appear on the blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to call [send](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send).

```
var newBox = Logistics.methods._createBox("0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10", "0xf25186b5081ff5ce73482ad761db0eb0d25abfbf")
    .send({ from: <0xFromAddress>, gas: <gas_amount> });
```